StreamBuilder not working with action_cable dart package
I'm building a simple chat system receive/send message with actioncable and flutter. I use devise_token_auth for communicating with the web sockets for the rails application. I installed a package called action_cable for flutter and setup a send method that does seem to work when submitting messages from flutter. My biggest issue here is connecting the stream to the stream builder and appending messages to the initialData that. How do I setup the stream to connect to action cable through the action_cable dart package with flutter? The data is flowing in one direction, doesn't dynamically insert into the listview and I don't have the streambuilder assigned to any stream from actioncable itself.
chatroom.dart
class _ChatroomState extends State<Chatroom> {
  dynamic chatroomData;
  File? imageUpload;
  late ImagePicker imagePicker;
  final messageController = TextEditingController();

  chooseImage() async {
    XFile? selectedImage =
        await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (selectedImage != null) {
      imageUpload = File(selectedImage.path);
      setState(() {
        imageUpload;
      });
    }
  }

  late Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> _chatroomData;
  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchChatroomData() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    final storageObj = await storage.readAll();
    var uid = storageObj['uid'];
    var accessToken = storageObj['access_token'];
    var client = storageObj['client'];

    final payload = json.encode({
      "uid": uid,
      "access-token": accessToken,
      "client": client,
      "id": widget.chatroomId,
    });

    try {
      final request = http.StreamedRequest(
          'GET',
          Uri.http(
            'localhost:3000',
            'api/v1/clients/chatrooms/${widget.chatroomId}',
          ));

      request.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
      request.sink
        ..add(utf8.encode(payload))
        ..close();
      final streamedResponse = await request.send();
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var chatroomDataObj = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

        setState(() {
          chatroomData = chatroomDataObj;
        });

        return chatroomData;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);

      return chatroomData;
    }

    return chatroomData;
  }

  List<ChatMessage> messages = [];

  Future<void> _sendMessageWebSocket() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    final storageObj = await storage.readAll();
    var uid = storageObj['uid'];
    var accessToken = storageObj['access_token'];
    var client = storageObj['client'];

    final cable = ActionCable.connect("ws://localhost:3000/cable", headers: {
      "Authorization": "$accessToken",
      "uid": "$uid",
      "access-token": "$accessToken",
      "client": "$client",
    }, onConnected: () {
      print('connected yay');
      
    }, onConnectionLost: () {
      print('connection lost');
    }, onCannotConnect: () {
      print('cannot connect no network');
    });

    cable.subscribe("Chatroom",
        channelParams: {"chatroom_id": widget.chatroomId},
        onSubscribed: () {},
        onDisconnected: () {},
        onMessage: (Map message) {
      print("message received here!");
      print(message);
      messages.add(ChatMessage(
          avatarUrl: message['avatar_url'],
          userInitials: message['user_initials'],
          messageContent: message['body'],
          imageAttachment: message['image_attachment'],
          userType: message['is_client']
              ? Color.fromRGBO(144, 144, 144, 1)
              : kPrimaryColor,
          createdAtTime: message['created_at']));
      setState(() {});
    });
   
    if (messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
      cable.performAction('Chatroom', action: 'send_message', channelParams: {
        "chatroom_id": widget.chatroomId
      }, actionParams: {
        "message": messageController.text,
        "client_id": chatroomData['client_id'],
        "chatroom_id": widget.chatroomId,
        "image": imageUpload
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _chatroomData = fetchChatroomData();
    imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScrollController _lvScrollCtrl = new ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _lvScrollCtrl.animateTo(_lvScrollCtrl.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: null,
        initialData: _chatroomData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!chatroomData.entries.isEmpty) {
            chatroomData['chat_messages'].forEach((e) {
              messages.add(ChatMessage(
                  avatarUrl: e['avatar_url'],
                  userInitials: e['user_initials'],
                  messageContent: e['body'],
                  imageAttachment: e['image_attachment'],
                  userType: e['is_client']
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(144, 144, 144, 1)
                      : kPrimaryColor,
                  createdAtTime: e['created_at']));
            });
          } else {
            messages;
          }

          return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                  title: const Text(
                    'FunChat',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white, size: 46),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ), //AppBar
                body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Text(
                          chatroomData['service_appointment_header']
                              .toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: kPrimaryColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 5),
                      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                            child: Divider(
                                color:
                                    const Color.fromARGB(255, 217, 217, 217)))
                      ])),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 50),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          controller: _lvScrollCtrl,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                          //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: messages.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 16, right: 16, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                              child: messages[index],
                            );
                          })),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                      height: 68,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          imageUpload != null
                              ? TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    removeImageAttachment();
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.close_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.red))
                              : Text(''),
                          imageUpload == null
                              ? Icon(Icons.camera,
                                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent)
                              : Image.file(imageUpload!),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              chooseImage();
                            },
                            onLongPress: () {
                              captureImage();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 30,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: kPrimaryColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: messageController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Write message...",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                                  border: InputBorder.none),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 50,
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      //  submitMessage(messageController.text,
                                      //    chatroomData['client_id']);
                                      _sendMessageWebSocket();
                                    },
                                    tooltip: 'Send Message',
                                    backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                                    elevation: 0,
                                    child: Icon(Icons.send,
                                        color: Colors.white, size: 26),
                                  )))),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ));
        });
  }
}

chatroom_channel.rb
class ChatroomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    if current_user
    stream_from "chatroom_#{params[:chatroom_id]}"
    else
      reject
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def send_message(data)
    @message = Message.new({body: data["message"], client_id: data["client_id"], chatroom_id: data["chatroom_id"], image: data["image"]})

    if @message.save
      message_obj = {id: @message['id'], body: @message['body'], chatroom_id: @message['chatroom_id'], created_at: ::ApplicationController.helpers.time_ago_in_words(@message['created_at']).dup.concat(' ago'), client_id: @message['client_id'], provider_id: @message['user_id'], is_client: @message['client_id'].present?, avatar_url: avatar_url_getter(@message['client_id'].present? ? @message['client_id'] : @message['user_id']), image_attachment: image_url_getter(@message), user_initials: user_initials(@message)}
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "chatroom_#{data["chatroom_id"]}", message: message_obj
    else
      Rails.logger.info "Errors: #{@message.errors.full_messages}"
    end
  end

  def received(data)
    puts "received data from action cable"
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('ChatroomChannel', data)
  end

  def self.avatar_url_getter(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    user.avatar.attached? ? Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(user.avatar) : ''
  end

  def self.user_initials(message)
    User.find(message['client_id'].present? ? message['client_id'] : message['user_id']).client_user_initials
  end

  def self.image_url_getter(message)
    message.image.attached? ? Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(message.image) : ''
  end
end


You have stream: null.  How do you expect that to do anything?

I'm trying to figure out how to use the stream parameter with action_cable dart package. I don't know where to go from here with it. I looked at the documentation and don't see anything that explains how it could be done.

Managing an incoming chat stream will likely require shared access.  Time to learn about state management, and setting up services that have perisistent state shared across many consumers.  I highly recommend Riverpod.

I'm using long polling instead.
